# Are memory-module blanks really important to have for a Dell PowerEdge T110 2 server? Or are they optional?

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge, physical-environment

I have removed and installed ram-chips from laptops and desktops before, but this is the first time I am doing it on a server (Dell PowerEdge T110 2). The hardware manual cautions that a memory-module blank must be installed if a ram-chip is removed for proper cooling of the system. My question is - since I don't have a memmory-module blank, should I really get one or can I simply remove the ram chip?

Some background:

Upon performing MemTest86, I found that one ram chip has a huge number of faults - which I believe is causing the server to crash daily. So, I am trying to remove that defective ram chip (I'll probably have to guess which of the 4 ram chips could be the defective one...)

Link to the hardware manual: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t110_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf

Thanks in advance to all for trying to help me out here!

Comment: Why would you guess which RAM module is bad? Why would you not run the Dell diagnostic tools and identify the bad RAM module?

Answer (score 2):

As it said, it *should* be in place for proper cooling of the server. If the server is in a 'safe' environment (ie, data center, or at least a dedicated equipment room with adequate cooling) then you should be fine to leave it out, especially if it's only a temporary situation while you get a replacement stick of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is critical for system cooling and you can remove it. Just to be sure use some tool for monitoring systems temperatures - if they don't exceed limits, than you can proceed using it "as is".

For example you can use [Aida64](http://www.aida64.com/) - it has stability test which will show you temperatures under peak loads

Comment: Why would you recommend a consumer PC benchmarking tool instead of recommending Dell OpenManage Server Administrator?

Comment: Because OMSA can only monitor current state, Aida can load cpu and ram to 100% and show temperatures in this state. This will give understanding of temperature levels with peak loads.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that if your system has adequate cooling then for the time being you can remove the memory module without adding a blank filler else you may have to add it. However, TBH it is better to replace the defective memory with a new memory rather than removing it and adding a filler in its place.

Try installing just a module in the first slot of the first channel and see if it works, repeat the process with all the other 3 modules one at a time and try to sort which one is defective. IMO, this should work and it is better.

I guess you knw what kinda memory your system has right now, so try getting the memory with the exact specs from whatever site you prefer like [crucial](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/Dell-memory/PowerEdge/PowerEdge+T110+II-upgrades.html), [memorystock](http://www.memorystock.com/memory/DellPowerEdgeT110II.html), newegg etc.